# Как сделать скрипт рабочим для любого исхода?

Tags: linux, bash, macos, shell, консоль

У меня имеется вот такой вот скрипт

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Welcome to the find script!"
echo "Commands - "
OPTION=0
while [ $OPTION -ne 7 ]
do
    echo "1.name"
    echo "2.size(M)"
    echo "3.directory"
    echo "4.How deep is it?"
    echo "5.How many days ago it was changed(+)"
    echo "6.Search"
    echo "7.Finish"
    read OPTION
    if [ $OPTION -eq 1 ]
    then
        echo "Give me the name of the file"
        read filename

    elif [ $OPTION -eq 2 ]
    then
        echo "Give me the size of the file(In M)"
        read size

    elif [ $OPTION -eq 3 ]
    then
        echo "Give me the directory of the file"
        read directory

    elif [ $OPTION -eq 4 ]
    then
        echo "How deep is it?"
        read deep

    elif [ $OPTION -eq 5 ]
    then
        echo "How many days ago it was changed?"
        read days

    elif [ $OPTION -eq 6 ]
    then
        echo "Searching for a files"
        find  $directory -iname "$filename*" -type f  -mtime +"$days" -size +"$size"M -maxdepth "$deep" 
    fi
done
echo "Exiting"
```

В целом он просто основан на команде find и исполняет определенные функции прописанные в цикле. У меня вот такой вопрос, как переделать этот скрипт, чтобы я мог в любое время нажать кнопку 6, и искать файлы по введенным параметрам? Например: я ввел только директорию, имя и размер файла, нажал 6, и он мне нашел нужные файлы. Ведь если я сделаю так в своем скрипте, у меня будет ошибка, мол введите числа для остального (deep,days). Я знаю что можно все исходы записать в 6, все будет работать, но при этом будут еще тексты ошибок(что не очень желательно).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из способов быстро сконструировать командную строку на основе переменных, которые могут быть пустыми:

```
find_args=()
[ -n "$filename" ]  &&  find_args+=(-iname "$filename*")
[ -n "$days"     ]  &&  find_args+=(-mtime +"$days")
// и так далее
find $directory "${find_args[@]}"
```

#### Приёмы использованные в отрывке выше

- Массивы bash. Если конструировать всё в обычной строке, то будут проблемы, когда в аргументах встретятся пробелы.

  - В частности, конструкция `"${file_args[@]}"` раскрывается в

    ```
    "${file_args[0]}" "${file_args[1]}" "${file_args[2]}" ...
    ```

  Это специальный вид раскрытия переменной обеспечивающий, чтобы все элементы массива оставались квотированными, аналогично `"$@"` для аргументов скрипта.
- Конструкция вида `[ -n "$filename" ] && foo` — это синоним

  ```
  if [ -n "$filename" ]; then
    foo
  fi
  ```

  Оная основана на том свойстве, что второй операнд `&&` выполняется только если первый вернул истину.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, все работает, только у вас ошибка в последней строке(не file_args, а find_args)

Comment: @AliakseiKlimovich, поправил

Comment: *&&* не синоним конструкции *if-then-fi*. Они очень похожи, но есть нюанс(ы).

Comment: @0andriy, на вскидку не могу придумать ни одного примера, где бы они вели себя по-разному...

Comment: Вот-вот, *shell* — очень непростой в освоении язык программирования. Удачи в поиске, если вам, конечно, азартно докопаться до истины.

Comment: @0andriy, договаривай уж, какой «нюанс(ы)» имел ввиду... конечно если это всё не просто словоблудие...

Comment: Что будет в каждом из вариантов, если *$filename* пуст или не существует?

Comment: @0andriy, абсолютно одно и тоже — `foo` не будет выполнен...

Comment: Эта часть абсолютно совпадает, вопрос, что будет сразу за этими строчками? (Даю ещё одну сильную подсказку: какие специальные переменные окружения будут установлены? Как именно в каждом из вариантов?)

Comment: @0andriy, а что будет? У меня под рукой `GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`, в обоих случаях отрабатывается одинаково. Разница, по-моему, только в том, что если после `&&` будет ошибка (`[[ "a" = "a" ]] && y || n`: `bash: y: command not found; bash: n: command not found`), то выполнится и `||`, в конструкции вида `if .. ; then .. ; else .. ; fi` такого не будет.

Comment: @imsysmem, вероятно любитель загадок имел в виду значение `$?`